# Android : Displaying ListView takes few seconds to display on first attempt

Tags: android, android-listview, android-dialogfragment

I have a custom `DialogFragment` with a custom `View` in it. That `View` has a `ListView` int it. I want to display it to instantly after I press a button or when an event is triggered. That `View` takes few seconds to display, 1 to 2 seconds, only during the first time that it is invoked. The next it has to appear, it appears instantly, or if has delay it only takes approximately 100-200ms.

I am creating new instance of the `View` every time it is invoked, so I'm thinking that it should also take few seconds to display.

Is there any solution for this? Thanks!

Sample Code:

```
CustomDialogFragment dialog = new CustomDialogFragment();
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "a_tag");
```

Here's the Dialog:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView mListView;
    private CustomAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Object> mData;


    public CustomDialogFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_fragment, container);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onActivityCreated(arg0);
        mListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lst);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mData = new ArrayList<Object>();
        mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), mData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO : Do something here
    }
}
```

Here's the `Adapter`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Object> data;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Object> d) {
        this.activity = a;
        this.data = d;
        inflater = ((LayoutInflater) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row, null);
        }
        // TODO : Edit some UI here
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ListView is probably taking some time to load. There might be heavy custom views with images etc in your ListView or it might have many elements.

You should profile and analyze your List adapter to see what exactly is causing the slow down.

You could maybe then try optimizing it by preloading the views before the activity is launched or some other technique of that sort.

The fact that it is happening only on first load indicates that the list items are being created. Once they are generated and in memory, displaying the list is going to be faster.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is there a way to load a `View`, it has `ImageView`s in it, without calling the `show()` method? Because, the `View` is being constructed only after calling the `show()` method?

Comment: You can use something like `Drawable d = context.getResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.image1)`. This loads the drawable into memory and keeps it there as long as there is a reference to it. Any view referring to the same drawable can quickly access it. You gotta be careful that you don't run out of memory and cause a crash though.

Comment: Another thing, I tried to remove the `Image` from `ImageView`, this serves as the background of the `View`, but it loads as fast as the original one, the one with background. So, I think it is not because of the images.